# Using ValueFilter in HBase shell throws RetriesExhaustedException followed by undefined method write for ValueFilter

Tags: hbase

I'm new to Hbase, using version 0.90.4-cdh3u3.  I'm trying to execute some queries to get a good understanding of HBase query syntax in the shell.  I created a table that contains hours worked for various employees.  A single row in the table looks like this:

```
hbase> scan 'Employees', {LIMIT=>1}
ROW                             COLUMN+CELL
 Alice                          column=Day:Friday, timestamp=1340903869525, value=Hours:2
 Alice                          column=Day:Monday, timestamp=1340903803699, value=Hours:4
 Alice                          column=Day:Thursday, timestamp=1340903855735, value=Hours:8
 Alice                          column=Day:Tuesday, timestamp=1340903821034, value=Hours:7
 Alice                          column=Day:Wednesday, timestamp=1340903836330, value=Hours:2
```

I want a query that shows which employees worked 8 hours and on which days.  So, I want to scan all the rows and look for any column that has a value equal to 8.  I am trying to use a ValueFilter because I saw that it scans all the columns without specifying them.  I've tried several renditions of my query and they all give the same error.

```
scan 'Employees', {LIMIT=>2, FILTER=>"ValueFilter(=, 'binary:8')"}
ROW                             COLUMN+CELL

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Trying to contact region server basecloud02.noviidesign.com:60020 for region Employees,,1340903535790.86c7a1240ef6c8c499cba43555af2af3., row '', but failed after 7 attempts.
Exceptions:
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method `write' for "ValueFilter(=, 'binary:8')":String
(this execption is repeated for each row)
```

I can't tell if it's my query thats incorrect or if something in the configuration is wrong...
Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm your region server is running? The following works for me on hbase 0.94                                                scan 'Employees', {LIMIT=>2, FILTER=>"ValueFilter(=, 'binary:Hours:8')"}

Answer (score 0):

Given that it tires to invoke 'write' method on supplied filter (which is what all implementations of Filter - extends Writable - need to implement), it seems like the version you are using does not support [Filter Language](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12490608/Filter%20Language%283%29.docx), which would allow for filter to be built from the string (via ParseFilter.parseFilterString).